# User Record Access

Tags: administration, permissions

For an custom object (say customer__c) In my two of the sandboxes, If I query for UserRecordAccess

```
[SELECT HasAllAccess, HasDeleteAccess, HasEditAccess, HasReadAccess, HasTransferAccess, MaxAccessLevel, RecordId FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = 'userId' AND RecordId= 'recordID']
```

getting different results.
In one org this query results in all access are true with MaxAccessLevel as 'All' but in another org all access levels are false with MaxAccessLevel as 'None' which results in in first org user able to see the records and in second records are not visible.

There is no separate permission set assigned to the user and my object org wide default is 'Public read/write' and at profile level no CRUD access provided to the object in both of the sandboxes still showing different behavior.

How to make all access to true and maxAccessLevel to 'All' for the user in another sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I bet this is through ModifyAll object permission. ModifyAll privileges can be set by assigned the user to a System Admin (called Admin through API) or assigning Delegated Admin profile or directly through the user's profile. Check the Object Permission for the object.

Good luck!

Sridhar

Comment: Small addition - might be ModifyAll permission on specific object type or it might be in the system permission which apply to all object types.